# Erro ao gerar APK assinado

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Quando eu vou assinar a `apk` para enviar a Play Store ocorre a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Error: Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static
>   [ValidFragment]

Alguém saberia me informar o que poderia estar acontecendo?

Veja o código [aqui](http://agenciaabound.com.br/java/FragmentoEnviarOracao.java).

Comment: Você tem um **SupportMapFragment** declarado no seu xml? Porque voce cria daquela forma ?

Comment: Sim estou @Thiago Luiz Domacoski.